# All Log4net IsErrorEnabled and sibling properties return false

Tags: c#, log4net

I have the below code :

```
public void LoggingAI(Exception ex)
{   
    var log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger((System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType));
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();

    if (log.IsInfoEnabled)
    {
        log.Error(ex);
    }
}
```

I have this below code in place in web.config

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="Info"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

I don't understand why all the properties, `log.IsInfoEnabled`, `log.IsErrorEnabled`, etc. are all `false`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes you are missing a lot of Log4Net configuration. Where are the Appenders. Also, XmlConfigurator has to be the First executed line and only after that you must call GetLooger.

Comment: I am not using any appender. I am using simple log4net Nuget.

Comment: Where would the Log4Net framework write logs to?? Appenders are the handlers which help you to log into File or Console or Database or Smtp etc.

Comment: I added the Application Insight Appaneder. But still same issue . Its unable to fetch the Root > Level value

Comment: always Error is enabled. Not sure why.

Comment: My first Comment had your fix. :)

Comment: I have Xmlconfiguration Prior to GetLogger. Still facing same issue.

Comment: Unable to repro your situation. For Info Level enabled. All trace levels except Debug are True. See the updated screenshot in my answer. What .Net version and Log4Net version are you using?

Comment: For Info , all are true except Debug. For Error (Error&Fatal are true) all are false.

Comment: Ah... so you are not aware of Hierarchy. Its Debug < Info < Warn < Error < Fatal. So whatever trace level you enable in the appConfig that and higher are ON/True/Enabled. All lower ones are disabled.

Comment: So this is expected behavior then?

Comment: Yes. Very much expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182569/discussion-between-titi-and-prateek-shrivastava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Configure() before you use anything in Log4Net.

[image]

Unable to reproduce your situation:

[image]

Firstly Add the below to the Config sections:

```
<configSections>
<!--- Other Stuff here --->
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
```

Secondly below is a sample Log4Net section Config:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <mapping>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <foreColor value="Green, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <foreColor value="Cyan, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <foreColor value="Yellow, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <foreColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="FATAL" />
        <foreColor value="Yellow, HighIntensity" />
        <backColor value="Red" />
      </mapping>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %class.%method%newline%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>          

    <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default level -->
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
    </root>    
  </log4net>
```